# Cold atoms in optical tweezers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cold-atoms

Can someone recommend a good reference for learning about cold atoms in/with optical tweezers? I am interested in both the theoretical and experimental aspects. On my own, I couldn't find any introductory material that was easy to understand. It could be a paper, book, or a section of a thesis.